# Super easy 5V to 3V conversion?

Tags: voltage-regulator, dc-dc-converter

What is the absolutely simplest way for a 10 year old child (not really) to get a 5V (350mA) phone charger to power an LED (3.0V) and a clock (1.5V)?
The clock is meant to run on a 1.5V battery, but since I want to install a small LED, I thought why not run both light and clock on the same power supply.

I need it to be not bigger than a cigarette pack (preferably smaller.)
I don't understand electronics jargon so please treat me like a child.

I originally thought I could just solder on some resistors but there's no info online I could use to be found.

Let me know if there's anything else I forgot to include.

Comment: When you say LED 3V - what do you mean? Do you have a specific LED in mind that is rated to this?

Comment: How much current does the LED consume? Or the clock? Where did you look if you literally found no info about resistors?

Comment: At least post he picture of your project. Given information is not sufficient to provide any answer.

Answer (score 3):

Rather than use words, here's a design you can play with. That should please your inner ten-year-old, or your actual ten-year-old.

Try this ([simulate it here](https://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgjCAMB0l3BWcMBMcUHYMGZIA4UA2ATmIxEPKQUhAQFMBaMMAKAHNwAWLkXXsDz5ooUVgCVuvYoSkVetWl1pJFUaAlYAXEChS89BhLMOiIjFNAwJsXUsuwpchPIWzqEXPGAx3KlMHxCCEDaABN6ADMAQwBXABstVgAnORk5MEI1BEDWWxBIgHcw5IB7AAcAHQBHdwhiaEcmFnVILhQKaEwUBAxCfRI8PvJFWDZMjsEBYkmhUw6ikoqauvA1mEg2QrlTKb42sW29-nAZ-YVWI6FM2j2wM8gU08ms5919M1w4S91jXWVdHg8P9FD97h0TiggecxKlwe9ph0ocDbvBHkczsi3id0Qi8fDTI9Ulj9LQsTjkPAfiSAdhsCYAbjyQc6bIcawAB4gLhgJCYYHGdxQiAGXgAFVKlQAzmANAA1aUAYXipQAxgBrPIuPj0kF8bWk0RMv43X4mfCHN7pHqydJEs0ga0m14qXIYjrpPZ2sFnU3w71AA)):
[image]

**What's going on?**

I've set up the sim with a 3V LED. The 510 ohm provides about 4.2mA to the LED. This is a good current to start with for most LEDs. If you want less or more brightness, adjust the load resistor.

The NPN transistor is set up as a *voltage follower* to make a crude linear regulator. The two resistors set the base at about 2.15V, which gives about 1.6V at the emitter. The transistor action will maintain this voltage even with variable current to the clock. This should be fine for a clock designed to work on a 1.5 (1.7 ~ 1.2V) battery.

You can use most common switching NPN types like the 2N3904 or 2N2222 for this, it's not too fussy.

And finally, the second 510 ohm on the NPN is for safety: it protects the transistor if the output to the clock is shorted, because, you know, ten-year-olds. It otherwise has no effect.

This can fit easily in a 1 sq. in space with through-hole components. The transistor is cheap - about a penny in high volume, a bit more from Digi-Key or Mouser in onesey-twosies. Buy a bunch in case you fry them.

---

Here's an improved version that uses a *Darlingtion pair* of transistors. This has better output regulation owing to the additional gain provided by the second NPN. They can both be the same kind, e.g., the 2N3904.

[Simulate it here](https://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgjCAMB0l3BWcMBMcUHYMGZIA4UA2ATmIxEPKQUhAQFMBaMMAKAHNwAWLkXXsDz5ooUVgCVuvYoSkVetWl1pJFUaAlYAXEJhS6UvfgYXgQjFNDxcZXDF2zE8kZfnUIuhSsWXYueZy4EbGRaABN6ADMAQwBXABstVgAnORk5MEI1BDBIVj8QSIB3MOSAewAHAB0ARxCIYmhsFCYWdRd9Qmg9BAxCQxI8PvJFWDZM-UEBYkmhFENdQpLy6rqzCAgYSDYiuXmBIWM83am%20F103I9YToUzaU7AZsVS0PBB014u32jR4a7PeIZaNhsLIgWJdp9jCDZFcXm5PoiMPofvBjl9dMiMVdIcoMYi3HlUjDdHiSUdQnB-iTwdhrKTFNTQQC%20PSrgAPECeEKYN6ENooPAQQG8AAqZSqAGcwBoAGpSgDC8TKAGMANb5QhvOkipSZBmidHGMB9FmfdGfdLGdJEllW853UQ5PI6cFI-TmswWaBceYggiYDA5QSUdS%20nCQGZgNAIQX8yZwEARGIJJKQrGPD0Z00W7Owh05-6nD5uG3Uh1ZFkm2R5IA).
[image]

Comment: The 500 ohm (Reference Designators - !) (actually, either 470 or 510 ohms) is not needed.  The transistor is acting as an emitter follower, and the clock does not need current limiting.

Comment: Falstad doesn't do reference designators. I include the collector resistor as protection (you know, for kids) in the event of an output short. I would expect the clock to have a sub-mA draw, so the losses are minimal. The 10k is there to let the emitter follow, and to set the open-circuit voltage.

Answer (score 2):

If it is not a high power LED, all it needs is a resistor.

The clock current draw is most likely so small it can be handled with resistor voltage divider down to 1.5V, perhaps with a capacitor to provide low impedance.

One way to regulate voltage for the clock is to have a red 1.6V LED powered up via a resistor, and provide the clock from the 1.6V over the LED.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest is to get a 1.5V linear voltage regulator to supply the clock.

I assume that with "small led" you mean a standard 20mA led. In this case, use a current limiting resistor of some hundred Ohm and drive the led directly from 5V.

Alternatively you can use a zener clamp circuit to get a (more or less) constant voltage. But *this only works for low-current applications* because the zener circuit will dissipate power and the output voltage will vary a little bit depending on the amount of current it has to source. For a device like a clock it should work.

Btq, both solutions have the advantage that the output voltage does not depend on the input voltage.

Comment: the led is one of those thin 3 cm long filaments used in some bulbs.

Comment: @EddieMeltzer do you know hiw much current/power it draws?

Comment: The clock probably runs on the smell of electricity from an AA or AAA battery. Since a mains PSU is available a simple voltage divider would do the trick. OP is looking for "the absolute simplest way" which an LDO regulator isn't, I suspect.

Comment: @Transistor I agree, a voltage divider would certainly work for the clock. Though, I can't think of a simpler and at the same time "clean" and reliable solution than a LDO IC...

Comment: LM317 for instance. LDO is too complicated.

Comment: @user263983 sorry, I confused linear regulators with LDOs... once again

Answer (score 0):

Use 3 diodes in series to get roughly +3V from +5V.

Use 5 diodes in series to get roughly +1.5V from +5V.

R2 is a small load in order for diodes D4, D5, D6, D7, D8 to turn on.

R1 is a current limiter for your led.

---

You may use diodes 1N4148:

https://www.digikey.com/en/products/filter/diodes-rectifiers-single/280?s=N4IgjCBcoGwJxVAYygMwIYBsDOBTANCAPZQDaIALGGABxwDsIAuoQA4AuUIAyuwE4BLAHYBzEAF9CYOHUQgUkDDgLEyIAAzM2nSD37CxkkAFoATHIX8AripKRyAVmbij5%2B%2BCFUKNZ0A

or diodes 1N4001:

https://www.digikey.com/en/products/filter/diodes-rectifiers-single/280?s=N4IgjCBcoGwJxVAYygMwIYBsDOBTANCAPZQDaIALGGABxwDsIAuoQA4AuUIAyuwE4BLAHYBzEAF9CYOHUQgUkDDgLEyIAAzM2nSD37Cx4ySABMasEIrr1EJuKA

---

[image: 5V to 3V and 1.8V conversion]

Comment: those are rectifier diodes?does it not matter which of those 2 i use at all?thanks.

Comment: He needs 350 mA. Diodes 1N4001 and 1N4007 have an average current of 1 A.

Comment: @Enrico: (1) He doesn't *need* 350 mA. That's what the supply is capable of. (2) The clock is going to draw such little current that the forward voltage drop of the diodes will be lower than you have calculated and you may fry the clock. Add in a load resistor for safety and simulate it. (3) The LED probably just needs a series resistor. Your three diodes don't limit the current.

Comment: You are right. I'll update the circuit later.

Comment: Most likely the LED will go up in smoke if connected only to those diodes.

Comment: Diodes don't have a predictable voltage drop unless you know the current. This could damage the clock.

Answer (score -1):

Let me help you, this is quite simple, put the clock and LED in series along with a 10ohm resistor. And that's it!

Comment: That would work if both required the same current which is most unlikely. Your solution will result in 5 V across the clock due to its low current requirement. Bad answer, I'm afraid.

Comment: No, the resistor will drop any excess voltage, think about it, the clock probably works at around 10mA, which the LED will force to be the current in the circuit... So 3v dropped by the LED, leaving 2v for the clock and resistor.... Look if you supplied 2 volts to the clock with a 10ohm resistor in series, wouldn't the clock work? I know you probably know more about electronics but this is just simple.

Comment: An AA alkaline battery has a capacity rating of 2500 mAh. Think about it. At 10 mA it would be flat in 250 hours (actually more like 500 h since that's a low discharge rate). That means that you'd need to replace the battery every three weeks. Since a typical clock will run off a standard AA cell for > year (> 8760 h) the current drawn is likely to be about 100 or 200 µA. The clock's equivalent internal resistance if it draws 100 µA at 1.5 V = 15 kΩ. Your 10 Ω series resistor will change this by 0.07%. It's not difficult but it's not so simple either.

Comment: Keep in mind, he's using a charger or 5v adapter thus the cell going flat isn't going to be an issue

Comment: You've completely missed the point. Your idea of limiting the voltage using a 10 Ω resistor won't work and will apply 5 V to the clock and probably destroy it. I used the battery calculations to show you that your 10 mA estimate for clock current was off by a factor of 100 or more.

Comment: No it wouldn't! It would apply two volts! Because 3 volts is dropped by the LED

Comment: No, 3 V is the forward voltage, \$ V_f \$ at a specified current. (Check the datasheet or look at LED I-V curves.) At reduced current the \$ V_f \$ will be reduced. The clock will be "over-voltaged" and the LED current will be to low to light it significantly thereby failing one of the requirements.